# How to call microsoft graph api from javascript in .net core project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have .net core project, where I need to call microsoft graph api. I already login and authenticated. But in some pages I need to fetch meeting room status and I need to call it from javascript to access token. I am following this tutorial but it not working: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript?tutorial-step=1

I am getting error at below lines:

```
 try {
            authResult = await msalClient.ssoSilent(msalRequest);

        } catch (err) {

            authResult = await msalClient.loginPopup(msalRequest).catch(error => {
                // handle error
            });

        }
```

Comment: If you have an asp.net core web application? MVC? Or you have an asp.net  core api application and you realized the sign-in module in your front-end application?

Comment: @TinyWang I have .net core web application and razor pages on UI. I already login into application as we asks user to login with Azure AD credential. This is not single page application. We use MVC. Now at some pages, to get data from graph api, I needs to call graph api directly from javascript. By which we I can create graphclient kind of thing or any other way by which I can call graph api?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an asp.net core MVC project and has integrate azure ad to let users sign in.

Then it means you realized the authentication in the server side, so if you need to call graph api in your client side, then you have to generate access token in the server side and then send the token to your page. This is my idea and here my test.

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebMvcApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace WebMvcApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_app_clientid",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
  }
```

StartUp.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}
```

and pls don't forget `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` method.

Then add login page `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and add it to layout:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

[image]